# Best practice for binding properties of controls within a DataTemplate?

Tags: wpf, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

I see that there have been a lot of question asked over the years, about how best to bind with data within a datatemplate, is there a best practice? In this case I want my MemoryCopyBtn to copy the text of the currently selected MemoryListItem TextBox, so that I can do work on it in the ViewModel.

I can find the ListView using Findname, but it will show null for a  ListViewItem on PageLoad.

I can put everything in the Memory model page, but I don't think that's best practice.

I see that that are various options for walking the visual code tree, but I want to do this during runtime, is that really the only way?

What are my options?
Thank you.

```
<ListView x:Name="ClipboardList"
                      xmlns:m="using:QuickieEdit.Models"
                      ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.MemoryItems}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="m:MemoryItem">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Button x:Name="MemoryCopyBtn"
                                             Content="Copy"
                                             Click="How to Copy currently selected
                                             MemoryListItem.Text?"/> 
                                <TextBox x:Name="MemoryListItem"
                                               Text="{x:Bind Memory, Mode=TwoWay}">
                               </TextBox>                                  
                           </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: On button click you want to copy text in TextBox which is in the same DataTemplate?

Comment: Yes. I want to copy the currently selected or focused ListViewItem's TextBox.Content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly - you want to copy text of textbox which is located together with the button you click, not some selected\focused textbox (otherwise that does not make sense, because you have a copy button for each item in your list view). If so, just use command:

```
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="m:MemoryItem">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button x:Name="MemoryCopyBtn"
                        Content="Copy"
                        Command="{Binding CopyCommand}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=MemoryListItem, Path=Text}" />
                <TextBox x:Name="MemoryListItem"
                         Text="{x:Bind Memory, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

And in your MemoryItem:

```
public class MemoryItem {
    public MemoryItem() {
        CopyCommand = new RelayCommand(Copy);
    }        

    public string Memory { get; set; }
    public ICommand CopyCommand { get; private set; }

    private void Copy(object argument)
    {
        var text = (string)argument;
        Console.WriteLine(text);
    }
}
```

Comment: That means you're creating an instance of `RelayCommand` for each item in the list. No the best solution in terms of scalability.

Comment: @DHN Instance of ICommand per item will have absolutely zero effect on scalability and perfomance.

Comment: Interesting, you're consuming memory with every instance, aren't you?

Comment: Sure, but so negligible amount, that in WPF application does not even worth mentioning. If you care about such things - you should not use bindings in the first place - imagine how many instances each binding creates! And better not use WPF even - something like QT will consume much less memory.

Comment: Well sure you're right. But if I do the things "sloppy here and here" in the end my application might have a bad performance and then I need to invest a large amount of time to identify the issues and solve them. So if I see such things, which can be easily avoided, why shouldn't I do so?

Comment: Main thing here that it will never ever lead to bad perfomance, not even contribute to it a little tiny piece. Then, it follows usual WPF practice to use commands to handle events, and makes code more readable than using click handlers and trying to find textbox there, at least for me. Using click handler is fine if you want so, but you should not do this just to save negligible amount of memory - if you found another solution more readable, that's already enough to prefer it. You may also read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize

Comment: @DHN: First of all, I love `Commands`, due to the reasons you have already mentioned. I would also agree with your opinion about optimization, if we wouldn't talk about a list, which can have any size...but well perhaps you're right...

Comment: Thank you very much Evk. I finally found some time to get back to this, and your solution worked perfectly. Since I am using Template 10, I was able to your code to help figure out to implement with this:                 public DelegateCommand<object> CopyCommand
        {
            get
            {
                _copyCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(Copy);
                Debug.Write(_copyCommand);
                return _copyCommand;
            }
}

Answer (score 1):

I think you can bind the Click event of Button in your `MemoryItem`, then you can get the data context of the clicked button in this event.

Just for test, I wrote a very simple demo here:

```
<ListView x:Name="ClipboardList" ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.MemoryItems}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:MemoryItem">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button x:Name="MemoryCopyBtn"
                                     Content="Copy"
                                     Click="{x:Bind MemoryCopyBtn_Click}" />
                <TextBox x:Name="MemoryListItem"
                                       Text="{x:Bind Memory, Mode=TwoWay}">
                </TextBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Code behind:

```
private MainPageViewModel ViewModel;

public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    ViewModel = new MainPageViewModel();
}
```

My MainPageViewModel class:

```
public class MainPageViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<MemoryItem> MemoryItems;

    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        MemoryItems = new ObservableCollection<MemoryItem>();
        MemoryItems.Clear();
        MemoryItems.Add(new MemoryItem { Memory = "Item 1" });
        MemoryItems.Add(new MemoryItem { Memory = "Item 2" });
        MemoryItems.Add(new MemoryItem { Memory = "Item 3" });
        MemoryItems.Add(new MemoryItem { Memory = "Item 4" });
        MemoryItems.Add(new MemoryItem { Memory = "Item 5" });
        MemoryItems.Add(new MemoryItem { Memory = "Item 6" });
        MemoryItems.Add(new MemoryItem { Memory = "Item 7" });
        MemoryItems.Add(new MemoryItem { Memory = "Item 8" });
    }
}
```

The MemoryItem class:

```
public class MemoryItem
{
    public string Memory { get; set; }

    public void MemoryCopyBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = ((FrameworkElement)e.OriginalSource).DataContext as MemoryItem;
        var text = item.Memory;
    }
}
```

This code here is not 100% same as yours, very simple just for test, please don't mind. In common cases, we avoid to use VisualTree Helper to do this work, x:Bind can be used for event, it's very useful here.

Comment: Thank you Grace Feng. I decided to go with Evk's Command approach below, mainly because I wanted to use the Command, but I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use purely x:Bind, I suggest you define the Click event in XAML, `Click="onButtonClicked"` . In the View, you call the ViewModel (in MVVM, the View knows the VM) OR you can publish a message, the ViewModel will catch it and do the work. MVVM Light has this Messenger mechanism.

Comment: Whether I call the ListViewItem in the ViewModel using FindName or in the View's code behind with SelectionChanged or on the Textbox itself with GetFocus, the ListviewItem.Content always comes back null. I guess what I'm looking for is a best practice for returning the currently selected or focused ListViewItem's content.

Comment: By content you mean the object which is binded to the list view item or the xaml content of the list view item ? If you want to access the object, you can get it from the `DataContext` of the sender object in the event handler. You can also use x:Bind to bind to event handler in your ViewModel, so you don't need to handle the event in the View anymore.